# Setting minute step on selector of boostrap-datetimepicker

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker

I use boostrap-datetimepicker, but in minute selector it just step on 00, 05, 10,... and so on, I want to step on 00, 01, 02, 03,..., 59, but I can not find any option to set that.
Anyone know another choice for me?